# Examples of Non-Quadratic Spaces in Physics

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor

While reading about GR I learned that while generalizing the ideas of geometry geometry we are interested in only quadratic spaces and space-times because they look like Euclidean space/ Lorentzian space-times at very small intervals.

I felt that this should be true for *any* physical geometrical object because I can't imagine how else any geometry can look at small distances. But then again there are many things that are impossible to imagine  so I wanted to ask:

1. Are non quadratic objects used in any other areas of physics to describe geometries/space-times or any quantities that are interpreted as geometries (shapes in velocity space,momentum space etc.)
2. If yes then (this is what I'm mainly interested in) what physical intuitions and analogies are used to describe them at small distances?

Comment: This post (v3) seems like a list question.

Comment: whats a list question?

Comment: what's a non-quadratic space?

Comment: Hi. Could you please clarify what you mean by: "While reading about GR I learned that while generalizing the ideas of geometry geometry we are interested in only quadratic spaces and space-times because they look like Euclidean space/ Lorentzian space-times at very small intervals." GR / solutions of Einstein's field equations produce a metric tensor that describe the local geometry of the spacetime. These are quadratic forms by definition, $ds^2 = g_{ab} dx^a dx^b$. I don't know what else they could be? Perhaps, you could elaborate?